# Use Sql server column alias in where condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a sql server query with one column as a expression like

```
Select name , name + age as Test from myTable
where Test like '%b%';
```

Now i cannot use Test either i need to write

```
Select name , name + age as Test from myTable
where (name + age) like '%b%';
```

Now the expression (name + age) can be very big sometimes so cant i give it some alias and use it

Any help is appreciated,

Thank You

Comment: May I know what is reason you want to do that way? You want to find any record that match your filter criteria in either name or age column?

Comment: @ThitLwinOo because sometimes my expression is too big so i want to use some alist, so i put the question here so that i may know whether this is possible or not

Comment: Ok, I provided one answer, please try. Let me know it is ok for what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this way..

```
select name, Test
(
Select name , (name + age) as Test from myTable
) t
where Test like '%b%'
```

The query needs to be modified as it has syntax error:

So it should be written like

```
select name from
(
Select name , (name + age) as Test from myTable
) t
where Test like '%b%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use cross apply like this

```
select M.name , T.Test
from myTable as M
  cross apply(select name + age) as T(Test)
where T.Test like '%b%';
```

Comment: +1 for Cross Apply. But it is little costlier affair if compared to Thit' answer.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure -  The tests I have made does not show any difference in query plans or execution times.

Comment: In the execution plan, `Compute Scalar` step is added, it addes to CPU cost. It's not very significant though, may be because my DB size is small.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure - There is a `Compute Scalar` step in the derived table query as well. (SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Cross checked, the query from Thit was giving different output. Now checked everything, looks same. No difference at all. My bad. Apologies.